# 2 digits only allowed once (Regex)

Tags: regex, unix

I'm trying to check if a level is valid or not.
The level is of the form: (but they're 998 more of these)

```
bbbbbbb
b41111b
b81400b
b81010b
b01121b
b08001b
bbbbbbb
```

The level must follow a few rules. I have written a regex to conform all rules but one:
The level must contain exactly 1 times 2 and 1 times 4.
(Notice in the level above there's two 4's and one 2. The level above is not valid.)

This is a school project so please guide me through to the answer.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

My current regex is:

```
^b{' + str(length) + r'}\n(b{1}[0-8]{' + str(length - 2) + r'}b{1}\n)+b{' + str(length) + '}$
```

For the level above, length = 7
Note that it doesn't even try to filter this wrong level above.
The other rules are:

1. The level must be surrounded by a 'b'
2. The level can only contain the char 'b' and numbers smaller than 9.
3. There can only be one 2
4. There can only be one 4

My regex above does take rules 1 and 2 into account, but I still need to figure out rules 3 and 4.

I have tried lookarounds and such, couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the regex that will meet all of your conditions:

```
^b(?!(?:[^2]*2){2,})(?!(?:[^4]*4){2,})[b0-8]*b$
```

- It starts and end with b Using `^b` and `$b`
- It comprises of only letter b and numbers 0-8 by`[b0-8]*`
- It won't allow more than one digit 2 by using `(?!(?:[^2]*2){2,})`
- It won't allow more than one digit 4 by using `(?!(?:[^4]*4){2,})`

Comment: 'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
b0000000000000b
b0233333303400b
b0111111111110b
b0000000000000b
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb'

Is a valid level but your regex doesn't grab it.

Comment: That's not correct. My regex grabs all of them see **live demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/1cOFdbuP5k**

Comment: I should've mentioned. I'm working in Python, does this make a difference?

Comment: That doesn't make any difference since python also supports lookaheads.

Comment: Yet, it doesn't work on pythex.org, neither in my script.
See: http://tinyurl.com/m99scwk

Comment: It needs Multiline, I suppose.

Comment: Actually it works on pythex.org` with multiline flag

Comment: yes because you are entering multiple new lines and regex is using `^` and `$`

Comment: I've changed [b0-8] to [b0-8\n] so now it works fine. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't require that the first and last lines are mad up solely of b's, which. while not explicitly stated, does appear to be required.  Should be easy to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a regex for exactly 1 `a` would be `[^a]*a[^a]*` (that is, a possibly empty sequence of non-`a`'s, followed by an a, followed by a possibly empty sequence of non-`a`'s).  I'll leave it an an exercise how to handle multiple lines & making sure this covers the whole level.

For exactly 1 `a` and 1 `b`: `[^ab]*((a[^ab]*b)|(b[^ab]*a))[^ab]*`, with the same caveats.  Explanation: a sequence of non-a-or-b's, follow by EITHER 1) an a, a run of non-a-or-b's, and a b, or 2) a b, a run of non-a-or-b's, and an a, with THAT followed by a run of non-a-or-b's.

Comment: I have tried and thought of this.
But the problem is, I need to do this for 2 characters (2 and 4), which complicates things.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use negative lookaheads anchored to start of input.

It's unclear what you're trying to match, so I will just use a placeholder `<your-regex>` for your current regex:

```
^(?!.*?2.*?2)(?!.*?4.*?4)<your-regex>
```

See a [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/lVNQFdA6bQ) of rhis correctly rejecting more than 1 "2".

Comment: I'm trying to understand this. Could you explain what this will do? I understand simple negative lookaheads but this looks rather complicated.

Comment: It's saying that there can't be more than 1 "2" (same for "4"). Note how this regex is a lot simpler than the accepted answer's look aheads. That's because it's using a *reluctant* quantifiers `*?` which will consume as little input as possible to match - so `.*` won't skip over a "2", which would break the intention (as opposed to a *greedy* quantifiers `*`, which won't work)